# Prevent two \psmatrix objects from connecting to each other

Tags: pstricks, psmatrix

I'm attempting to draw graphs using pstricks' `\psmatrix` command with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}

\def\e{\strut \hphantom{.}}

\newenvironment{graph}
               {
                 \begin{center}
                  $\psmatrix[rowsep=1cm,colsep=1.5cm,mnode=circle]
               }
               {
                 \endpsmatrix
                 $
                 \end{center}
               }

\begin{document}

\begin{graph}
  \e & \e & \e & \e & \e
  \ncline{1,1}{1,2}
  \ncline{1,2}{1,3}
  \ncline{1,3}{1,4}
  \ncline{1,4}{1,5}
\end{graph}

\begin{graph}
  & \e \\
  \e & \e & \e & \e
  \ncline{1,1}{1,2}
  \ncline{1,2}{1,3}
  \ncline{1,3}{1,4}
  \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
\end{graph}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output, where the top row of circles come from the first graph, and the second and third rows are from the second graph:
[image: Two graphs which are inappropriately connected]

I would expect that every pair of `\psmatrix`, `\endpsmatrix` would be independent of each other, but instead the two graphs seem to be using the same set of nodes. For example, if I remove all of the `\ncline`s from the first graph, I get this result:
[image: Weird graph that I don't understand.]

How would I separate the two graphs so that code from one doesn't affect the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct behaviour! Your second example has only one cell in the
first row, the reason why the `\ncline` will take the cells from the first
row of the first example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}

\def\e{\strut \hphantom{.}}

\newenvironment{graph}
{
    \begin{center}
        \psmatrix[rowsep=1cm,colsep=1.5cm,mnode=circle]
    }
    {
        \endpsmatrix
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{graph}
    \e & \e & \e & \e & \e
    \ncline{1,1}{1,2}
    \ncline{1,2}{1,3}
    \ncline{1,3}{1,4}
    \ncline{1,4}{1,5}
\end{graph}

\vspace{1cm}
\psset{linecolor=red}

\begin{graph}
    \e & \e & \e & \e\\
    \e & \e & \e & \e
    \ncline{1,1}{1,2}
    \ncline{1,2}{1,3}
    \ncline{1,3}{1,4}
    \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
\end{graph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. I understand now where I went wrong. I had the indexes backwards. It's surprising, though, that it takes nodes from the previous psmatrix, rather than either initializing empty nodes or throwing an error.

Comment: {1,3} is taken als nodename. And it is not redefined in the second example